# Messaging.sendEmail not compiling for some reason

Tags: apex

I have the following method that has been working fine until today, I have not changed anything with the code.

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    if(cc != null) { mail.setCcAddresses(cc); }   
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setReplyTo('******');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Messaging');
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

When I try to deploy I get:

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sendEmail(List) from the type Messaging

This started today in both Sandbox and Production.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: is your apex class Name `Messaging` ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal this is an Apex class https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm

Comment: Does the above code you posted, is inside a class named as `Messaging` ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  No

Comment: what is the API version of the class? is it latest 47.0 ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it's version 46.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Messaging` namespace is being "shadowed" by a variable or class by the same name. If you did not change that class, odds are, someone created a new class in your org called `Messaging`, which in turn would cause compilation errors for any classes that use the standard `Messaging` library. You'll want to remove or rename that class so it does not conflict with your code.